# Why is "Plus rien ne me choque" composed like this?

Tags: grammaire, négation, ordre-des-mots

In the sentence

> Plus rien ne me choque

(Which is supposed to be translated as "Nothing shocks me anymore") Why isn't it like

> Rien ne me choque plus

Why is the ne plus inverted and put on the rien instead of the verb?

Comment: La seconde proposition est utilisée dans les phrase : "*Rien ne me choque plus* que de voir ...", le sens de plus est donc inversé, alors que la première phrase ne peut induire la même lecture.

Comment: Donc, la seconde proposition est seulement utilisée dans cette seule phrase, ou non? Parce que je suis confus pourquoi il y a un "ne", puisque "ne plus" traduit "Not anymore"

Comment: @Marco Ruben Abuyuan Llanes: En français, "*Rien*" est obligatoirement suivi par *"ne/n'"*. **Nothing** se traduit donc en **Rien ne**.

Comment: Ah! Okay, hahaha je suis si bête hahaha

Comment: @MadWard Sur la [page wikipedia de Rien](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rien), il y a la phrase _« Il est parti de rien, de moins que rien ! »_. Est ce que ce n'est pas un contre exemple ? A moins que la phrase correcte soit  _« Il **n'** est parti de rien, de moins que rien ! »_ ?

Comment: @Thomas Francois: Comme tu l'as très bien dit, le *ne* ou *n'* est parfois omis dans des conversations informelles comme à l'oral ou sur Internet avec des amis. La phrase correcte est bien *"Il n'est parti de rien*." Voir: [Omission de "ne"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A9gation_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Omission_de_.C2.AB_ne_.C2.BB) et [Négation avec rien](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-72687.php)

Comment: You ask about “choquer” and maybe it’s different with other verbs, but I’ve seen/heard the construction that you’re asking about in a translation of Bob Dylan’s [*Adieu Angélina*](http://www.metafilter.com/122651/Farewell-Angelina-by-Joan-Baez-Bob-Dylan-and-Nana-Mouskouri-among-others) with “aller”:... “Dans la salle du tout va … **rien ne** va **plus** pour moi.” (granted, it’s a song [& a translation of one, to boot], so maybe poetic license explains/permits the **plus** [with its negative, "not anymore" sense] after the verb)

Comment: @MarcoRubenAbuyuanLlanes much better question than those you were asking a couple months ago! Also, did you say you just started learning French *two or three months ago*? Because you seem to have come an incredibly long way very fast.

Comment: Well haha I don't have any personal teachers so that's why I ask stupid questions. I've actually been learning for a year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually both forms are correct.

Though the former (sticking *plus* to *rien*) puts more emphasis on the quantity of things that are non-shocking :

> **Plus rien** ne me choque, (maintenant).
>   ***Toutes les choses*** ne me choquent plus, maintenant.
>   ***All the things*** don't shock me anymore.
>   **Nothing** shocks me anymore.

Whereas the latter (sticking *plus* with the implicit "now") puts more emphasis on the *timely* aspect :

> Rien ne me choque **plus**, (maintenant).
>   Rien ne me choque, ***plus maintenant***.
>   Some things use to shock me, but ***not anymore***.
>   Nothing shocks me **anymore**.

(Note that *plus* can ambiguously mean either "more" and "no more", so the latter can be misinterpreted to mean "nothing shocks me more that that" = "this is the most shocking thing ever".)

Comment: Another difference is that "Rien ne me choque plus" is ambiguous in writing. When "plus" is pronounced with a silent s, it means "Nothing shocks me anymore"; when the s is pronounced, it means "Nothing shocks me more". "Plus rien ne me choque" is not ambiguous that way.

Comment: @qoba: Is this not what my last paragraph is saying ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. Maybe you should mention explicitly that the former sentence doesn't have that ambiguity; it's also maybe not so minor; your answer makes it sound like the main difference is emphasis, but at least for me, avoiding ambiguity rather than emphasis would be the chief reason for preferring the first sentence in writing.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are valid although most people would use the first one, the latter sounding more literary. *Plus* does not relate to the verb.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, but the second one is ambiguous when written, because if you don't pronounce the "s", it means "Nothing shocks me anymore", but if you pronounce it, it means "Nothing shocks me more"...

And it's not even that simple, because some people NEVER pronounce the "s" in "plus", so you can't even be sure of what they would mean when saying the second one.